# Snackbar is not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter,Here I can't find why my snackbar is not showing in the ui.I tried exactly like the documentation .

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
          onPressed: () {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Undo',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the call to `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)` makes Flutter search the widget tree for ancestors of type `ScaffoldMessenger` and it's not able to find one.

This happens, because you pass in the `BuildContext` of the widget **under** which the Scaffold is declared. But it searches in the opposite direction.

One solution to this is, to wrap the call to `ScaffoldMessenger.of` in a `Builder` widget, wich introduces a new `BuildContext`. Then Flutter is able to find a ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree and use it to show the SnackBar.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  final snackBar = SnackBar(
                    content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
                    action: SnackBarAction(
                      label: 'Undo',
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  );
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                },
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check out the `Builder` documentation, it explains everything about those `.of()` methods: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code for displaying SnackBar in flutter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SnackBarDemo());

class SnackBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SnackBar Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('SnackBar Demo'),
        ),
        body: const SnackBarPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
          );

          // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
          // and use it to show a SnackBar.
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Photo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, You may missed forgot to wrap your scaffold
with `MaterialApp();`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
          onPressed: () {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Undo',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```